# react-pdf-js throwing unhandled proise exception on IE11

Tags: reactjs, pdf-viewer, react-pdf

I am using `react-pdf-js "^4.0.2"`, with `"react": "^15.6.1"`, the plugin is working fine on chrome, firefox and IE edge. But it is throwing network error and unhandled promise rejection errors on IE 11.

Since this is  third party plugin i installed through npm, I am not sure how can i handle and make it work for IE11.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf-js

This is how I am using it in my react component passing base 64 data

```
<PDF className={this.state.showBorder ? "pdf-border" : ""}
    file={...base 64 data...}
    page={this.state.page}
    onDocumentComplete={this.onDocumentComplete}
/>
```

Anybody has an insight on this?

console screenshot attached :

[image]

Comment: Please paste text messages as text here, not as pic.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
import { Document } from 'react-pdf/build/entry.noworker';
```

Comment: I think you are talking about a different plugin- react-pdf. I am using react-pdf-js

Comment: so problem is with your pdf.js. so better upgrade your pdf.js   with  https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap